# Linux Shell Scritping - checking arguments

Tags: linux, shell

Trying to make a program where it takes two arguments from the command line and adds them together. However if there are not two arguments passed it needs to ask for two arguments.

```
if [$# = 2]; then
ans=$(($1 + $2))
echo "$1 + $2 = $ans"
else
echo "Pass me two Arguments!"
fi
```

What is the correct way to check whether the number of arguments is equivalent to a number?

Answer (score 2):

You got it but just forgot some escaping quotes and the spaces before/after the test (`[$# = 2]`). Fixed:

```
if [ "$#" = 2 ]; then
ans=$(($1 + $2))
echo "$1 + $2 = $ans"
else
echo "Pass me two Arguments!"
fi
```

Odd as it may seem, `[` is actually the name of an executable just like `echo`, `ls` and what have you:

```
$ which [
/usr/bin/[
```

This means that if you don't have a space after `[`, you're trying to start a program called `[your_statement`. The space is needed to separate the executable from its arguments.

Most *nix systems allow you to use the equivalent `test` executable rather than `[` for a more intuitive syntax: `if test "$#" = 2; then ...`

By omitting the quotes in the `if` statement, bash/shell interprets everything following the `#` as a comment and so does SO's code formatting tool (everything after `if [$` is greyed out in your code but not in mine because I added the double quotes in `"$#"`).

Btw. [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) can be very helpful.